# Magento 2 how to add external css and js library with RequireJS?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs-config.js

I'm struggling trying to add this js library [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

This is what I've tried to add both, css and js:

in Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml i have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
         <css src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

The reason of why i'm using cms_index_index.xml instead of default_head_blocks.xml is because I want the library just be available in the home page.

Now for javascript I have this:
Theme/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle',
            'aos':"https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos"
    } ,
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'aos': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

Bootstrap is working fine by the way.

Finally in Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">require(['bootstrap','aos']);</script>
```

I practically did the same as I did for bootstrap, because bootstrap is working fine, but I don't know why AOS is not working. It should work just by adding classes like bootstrap.

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: Do you have any errors? If you console log aos what is logged?

Comment: When I use require(['bootstrap','aos'],function () {
    AOS.init();
}); I get the error that AOS is not defined, but the library says that it needs to be initialize by that way, besides that, there are no errors.

Comment: See my updated comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I mis-read the original issue. The script is probably loading, but it looks like you're expecting it to be available in the global scope.

The AOS library is AMD-aware in that if it detects it's being loaded by RequireJS, it will "scope" it down to that requested instance. The `require` call accepts a second parameter of a callback function. If you create a function there and add `aos` as a parameter of the function you can use it:

```
require(['jquery', 'aos'], function ($, aos) {
    // "aos" is now an object for the AOS library
    aos.init();
});
```

To validate that you're actually downloading the source, in chrome you can open the developer tools and look at the `Sources` tab to see if `unpkg.com` is in there with the `aos.js` file:

[image: Sources panel showing unpkg.com]

I tested this by adding it to one of my `requirejs-config.js` files in our theme like so:

```
var config = {
    deps: [
        "js/theme-custom"
    ],
    paths: {
        slick: 'js/slick',
        aos: 'https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not sure about the bootstrap working with just the `require(['bootstrap'])`. It may be that that bootstrap library exposes itself to the `window` object to make it global instead of staying scoped, but that's just a guess.

---

**Original Response**

RequireJS auto-appends `.js` to all paths in the config. Try adding a query parameter to the URL prevent this from happening:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
            'bootstrap':'Magento_Theme/js/bootstrap.bundle',
            'aos':"https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos?1"
    } ,
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'aos': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

Answer based on information from [Coderwall "Requirejs and external scripts"](https://coderwall.com/p/y4vk_q/requirejs-and-external-scripts)

Comment: Hi, I tried but did not work :(

Comment: Updated because I misunderstood the issue. @OscarVazquez

Comment: I checked in sources and It seems that the library is loaded correctly. I changed it to footer.phtml but it's still not working :( if I type this inside the require function aos.init(); it throws an error saying that it's not a function, in documentation I need to initialize in this way.

Comment: With the above requirejs-config, the following inline script worked for me (as far as I can tell as I'm not using AOS): `<script type="text/javascript">require(['jquery', 'aos'], function ($, aos) { console.log("AOS Initializing");  aos.init();  console.log("AOS Initialized"); });</script>` @OscarVazquez

Comment: It works now! my error was not including the jquery and $ symbol in require and function, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I updated the answer to show an example that actually works.